# Amazon Lightsail Oauth2 Google signup generates Error: invalid_request Permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

```
@app.route('/login')
def showLogin():
    state = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
                for x in xrange(32))
    login_session['state'] = state
# return "The current session state is %s" % login_session['state']
return render_template('login.html', STATE=state)


@app.route('/gconnect', methods=['POST'])
def gconnect():
# Validate state token
    if request.args.get('state') != login_session['state']:
    response = make_response(json.dumps('Invalid state parameter.'), 401)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return response
# Obtain authorization code
code = request.data
try:
    # Upgrade the authorization code into a credentials object
    oauth_flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', scope='')
    oauth_flow.redirect_uri = 'postmessage'
    credentials = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(code)
except FlowExchangeError:
    response = make_response(
        json.dumps('Failed to upgrade the authorization code.'), 401)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return response
# Check that the access token is valid.
access_token = credentials.access_token
url = ('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=%s'
       % access_token)
h = httplib2.Http()
result = json.loads(h.request(url, 'GET')[1])
# If there was an error in the access token info, abort.
if result.get('error') is not None:
    response = make_response(json.dumps(result.get('error')), 500)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return response
# Verify that the access token is used for the intended user.
gplus_id = credentials.id_token['sub']
if result['user_id'] != gplus_id:
    response = make_response(
        json.dumps("Token's user ID doesn't match given user ID."), 401)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return response
# Verify that the access token is valid for this app.
if result['issued_to'] != CLIENT_ID:
    response = make_response(
        json.dumps("Token's client ID does not match app's."), 401)
    print "Token's client ID does not match app's."
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return response
stored_access_token = login_session.get('access_token')
stored_gplus_id = login_session.get('gplus_id')
if stored_access_token is not None and gplus_id == stored_gplus_id:
    response = make_response(json.dumps('Current user is connected'), 200)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return response
# Store the access token in the session for later use.
login_session['access_token'] = credentials.access_token
login_session['gplus_id'] = gplus_id
# Get user info
userinfo_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"
params = {'access_token': credentials.access_token, 'alt': 'json'}
answer = requests.get(userinfo_url, params=params)
data = answer.json()
login_session['username'] = data['name']
login_session['picture'] = data['picture']
login_session['email'] = data['email']
# See if a user exists, if it doesn't make a new one
user_id = getUserID(login_session['email'])
if not user_id:
    user_id = createUser(login_session)
login_session['user_id'] = user_id
output = ''
output += '<h1>Welcome, '
output += login_session['username']
output += '!</h1>'
output += '<img src="'
output += login_session['picture']
output += ' " style = "width: 300px; height: 300px;border-radius: 150px;'
output += '-webkit-border-radius: 150px;-moz-border-radius: 150px;"> '
print "done!"
return output
```

I ran this OAuth code on my local machine. It worked but on Amazon Lightsail instance it gave the following error:

> *Error: invalid_request Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.

[image]

I even corrected my Redirect Uris and JAVA Script Origins to .com but it still gives the same error even on erasing the cookies.